# How can I load a module after consent using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies, recaptcha

I'm using Angular and the `RecaptchaV3Module` and  the `ngx-cookieconsent` module.
I would like to load recaptcha module if and only if user consent for the cookies via cookieconsent.
I know I can use lazy-module in routing but outside of it I don't have a clue.

here is a sample of my app module

```
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    ...,
    RecaptchaV3Module,
    NgcCookieConsentModule.forRoot(cookieConfig)
  ],
  entryComponents:[],
  providers: [
    ...,
    { provide: RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY, useValue: 'my-key' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I also have events for cookie consent in `app.component.ts` but don't know how to make them work together the best way.
Please let me know if you need more code.